# how to add discount on custom option by qty in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, discount

how to add discount on custom option by qty in Magento 2?
on add to cart
magento version 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below step.

1. log in the admin page.
2. from the left bar click CATALOG -> Products.
3. Search your targeted item.
4. Scroll down in the product detail and find "Customizable option"
5. Add options (When you add option you can give price with negative value (example, -7) then It will be discount.

Comment: if i add more then 5 qty. then need to 3% discount on custom option 
please help in this condition